# Simulating WiFi connection in iPhone simulator

Tags: xcode, client-server, virtual-machine, ios-simulator, esp8266

I am porting an Android app to iOS platform. In Android app, I use socket programming to make the mobile as a client and connect to ESP8266-12E WiFi module (Server) and send data to it.

I am using [SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket) to make the Apple device as the client. In my logic, if the connection failed with the ESP8266 it shows an Alert dialog. In Android Simulator in my Android studio application, this app works fine. It connects to the ESP8266 and communicates with it. But in the iOS version, it always fails to connect.

For More information. I do not own a Mac device or and Apple iPhone. But I really like to get into the development. So i run MacOSX Sierra in my Gaming Laptop (MSI GS72 6QE, 6700 HQ, 16GB ram, GTX970m 3GB) using VMWare as a virtual machine. I do not know if this (Running virtual machine) is causing the issue.

Since i do not own a iPhone either i do not know about the iOS. Checked in the simulator there is no option to enable wifi in the settings like in Android platform.

Can anyone Suggest a way to simulate a wifi connection inside the iPhone simulator and connect with the ESP8266

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't support running macOS in violation of its license agreement on non-Apple hardware.

The Simulator uses the mac host kernel and so uses normal mac networking. It should be relatively easy to create a test mac terminal utility that attempts to connect. If that doesn't work then your VM's network configuration is probably set incorrectly. You may need bridged mode.